# merge two data objects by matching 3 columns in R

Tags: r

I have two files and the following columns (given below are the column names) in two data objects (`segs2` and `tn`).

```
names(cbind(segs2[,2:6]))
[1] "chrom"     "loc.start" "loc.end"   "num.mark"  "seg.mean" 

names(cbind(tn[,4:10]))
[1] "num_positions"      "normal_depth"       "tumor_depth"        "adjusted_log_ratio"
[5] "gc_content"         "region_call"        "raw_ratio"  

names(cbind(tn[,1:10]))
 [1] "chrom"              "chr_start"          "chr_stop"           "num_positions"     
 [5] "normal_depth"       "tumor_depth"        "adjusted_log_ratio" "gc_content"        
 [9] "region_call"        "raw_ratio"
```

I tried merging by chromosome, start and stop position that is common in both the files but have different header names (a suitable script would help in automating analysis for many files);

> filenum <- cbind(segs2[,2:6], tn[,1:10], by=c("chrom","loc.start","loc.end","chr_start","chr_stop"))

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1146, 829244, 5

```
file_num <- cbind(segs2[,2:6], tn[,1:10], by=c("chrom","loc.start","loc.end","chrom","chr_start","chr_stop"), check.names=TRUE)
```

However this didnt work, is there an alternative ?

Thanks

Uma

Comment: Who told you `cbind` takes a `by` argument? Have a look at `?merge`.

Comment: thats true.. filenum <- merge(segs2[,2:6], tn[,4:10], by.segs=c("chrom","loc.start","loc.end"),by.tn=c("chrom","chr_start","chr_stop")) Not sure if it works thou

Answer (score 3):

As mplourde alluded to, I think what you want is:

```
merge(segs2, tn, 
      by.x=c("chrom", "loc.start", "loc.end"),
      by.y=c("chrom", "chr_start", "chr_stop"))
```

You can use `by.x` and `by.y` to specify which columns should be matched if the names differ.